# How to check whether ASP.NET button is clicked or not on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I check whether a particular button was clicked or not in ASP.NET?

I think I need to perform some operation on `Page_Load`. This shouldn't be entering to `Button_Click` event to find. Is there any way that I can find where it was clicked or not on Client Side and take it to `Page_Load`?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do in on `Page_Load`? Why can you not handle it on button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got the same trouble, have to do some logic judgement in the Page_Load method to treat different event(which button was clicked).
I realize the arm to get the as the following example.
The front end aspx source code(I have many Buttons with IDs F2, F3, F6, F12.

```
<Button Style="display: none" ID="F2" runat="server" Text="F2:Cancel" OnClientClick="SeiGyo(this)" OnClick="F2_Click" />
    <Button Style="display: none" ID="F3" runat="server" Text="F3:Return" OnClientClick="SeiGyo(this)" OnClick="F3_Click" />
    <Button Style="display: none" ID="F6" runat="server" Text="F6:Run" OnClientClick="SeiGyo(this)" OnClick="F6_Click" />
    <Button Style="display: none" ID="F12" runat="server" Text="F12:Finish" OnClientClick="SeiGyo(this)" OnClick="F12_Click" />
```

The back end aspx.cs source code, what I need to do is judge which button was clicked when Page_Load was triggered. It seems a little stupid, but works.
In your situation, the button be clicked will be added into dic.  I hope that will be helpful to some one.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(var id in new string[]{"F2","F3","F6","F12"})
{
       foreach (var key in Request.Params.AllKeys)
                    {
                        if (key != null && key.ToString().Contains(id))
                            dic.Add(id, Request[key.ToString()].ToString()); 
                    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using <asp:Button>, it should be sufficient to loop over Request.Form.AllKeys rather than Request.Params.AllKeys.  You can also filter out keys that start with "__" to save a little time.  Only the clicked button's ID will appear among the Form keys.

Answer (score 16):

**Background:** Basically  `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT` , These two Hidden controls are added to the HTML source, when ever any autopostback attribute is set to true for any of the web control.

The `__EVENTTARGET` hidden variable will tell the server ,which control actually does the server side event firing so that the framework can fire the server side event for that control.

The `__ EVENTARGUMENT` variable is used to provide additional event information if needed by the application, which can be accessed in the server.

So we can easily get the control causing postback using:`Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");`

***PROBLEM:***

***The method: `Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");` will work for `CheckBoxes`, `DropDownLists`, `LinkButtons`, etc.. but  this does not work for Button controls such as `Buttons` and `ImageButtons`***

The `Button` controls and `ImageButton` controls does not call the `__doPostBack` function. Because of this, the `_EVENTTARGET` will always be empty. However, other controls  uses javascript function  `__doPostBack` to trigger postback.

So, I will suggest to do something as below. Add an `OnClientClick` property to the buttons. Also, define a hiddenField in your Markup, whose value will contain the actual button causing postback.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"
     OnClientClick = "SetSource(this.id)" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"
     OnClientClick = "SetSource(this.id)" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidSourceID" runat="server" />
```

On the `OnClientClick` property of the `Button` and `ImageButton` Call the `SetSource` JavaScript function

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function SetSource(SourceID)
    {
        var hidSourceID =
        document.getElementById("<%=hidSourceID.ClientID%>");
        hidSourceID.value = SourceID;
    }
</script>
```

Here onwards, you can very easily check in your `Page_Load` as to which Control caused postback:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    string CtrlName;
    CtrlName=hidSourceID.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The UniqueID of the button will be in Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]

This question is already answered at: [ASP.NET : Check for click event in page_load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188584/asp-net-check-for-click-event-in-page-load)

Comment: not sure if things have changed, but no, the ASP.NET Button UniqueID does not appear in __EVENTTARGET for me. Which seems to validate what FlopScientist says above -- that this only works for "CheckBoxes, DropDownLists, LinkButtons, etc.. but this does not work for Button controls such as Buttons and ImageButtons"

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the hidden field. Make the client side event on the OnclientClick event and try setting the value of hidden field, may be true or false depending on the condition.
And on the page load you can check the value of Hiidden field.

```
function click()
{
// set the hidden field here
}
```

And on the page load, simply check the value.

```
if(HiddenFieldName.Value=="true")
{
//perform the action
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    private bool button1WasClicked = false;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1WasClicked = true;
    }


if ( button1WasClicked== false)
{
//do somthing
}
```

Comment: Here in my code I am not firing button1_Click Event. Intially PageLoad Fires and Just wanted to know in PageLoad Whether the button is clicked or not

Comment: Page_Load fires before any event handlers.