# reference element added during page load

Tags: c#

How is it possible to reference an element that is added to the html during pageload?

In my example I am trying to click a butten with the id of Clicker during page load.

However, because it is added to the html during page load, i get context error.

Error:
***Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'clicker' does not exist in the current context***

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//add button to html
locationsTable.InnerHtml = htmlString;

//click the button
clicker.PerformClick();
}

 htmlString += "<td><button id=\"clicker\" runat=\"server\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-xs\" onclick=\"return false;\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal\"></span></button>" + " " + "<a href=\"ModifyOrder.aspx?cid=" + row["CustomerID"] + "\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs\">Add License</a></td>";
```

This htmlString is added to an html table (along with other elements, but they are irrelevant) during page load.

```
locationsTable.InnerHtml = htmlString;
```

Comment: I think you're confusing javascript with c#

Comment: nope ...............................

Comment: Let's clarify then. Are you trying to perform an action when the user clicks the button with the id="clicker" that is found in html of the page?

Comment: yes. The action can be anything. I just trying to target the element with the ID of clicker. The problem is that clicker hasnt been added to the DOM yet. So the C# compiler cannot find it. So I get reference error.

Comment: According to the C# compiler "clicker" doesn't exist. Because it doesnt get added to the html, or the .aspx page, until after page load. So how can I assign anything to the button clicker?

Answer (score 0):

> `onclick=\"return false;\"`

You cannot put c# code inside HTML like that, as it will literally turn into HTML code (it's a string, not code).

However, if you want to know have an event listener for the `OnClick` event hooked up to an `id`, I believe that this code snippet from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188584/asp-net-check-for-click-event-in-page-load), can do the trick...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    locationsTable.InnerHtml = htmlString;
    htmlString += "<td><button id=\"clicker\">Add License</a></td>";

    if(IsPostBack){
        var eventTarget = Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"]
        var buttonClicked = eventTarget.Substring(eventTarget.LastIndexOf("$") + 1).Equals("clicker")
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to click the button?